# Gap between poor and rich in the Roman Empire

Tags: economy, roman-empire, social-class

Was the difference in purchasing power between the poor and the wealthy in the Roman Empire, greater than or less than than the difference between rich and poor people in modern western economies?

Given the breadth in time and diversity in Gini coefficient in "modern western economies", the answer should probably focus on the methodology for reaching an answer, rather than specific values for the answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unanswerable.

Comment: 1) You're projecting your image of contemporary class society backwards 2000 years, not acceptable.  2) "Buying power" is a concept that only develops in modern capitalism, similarly with "political regime" as you mean it, and also "wealth" and "accumulation."  This question is so theoretically loaded with anachronism that it can't be answered.  Its impossible to construct a meaningful wage price series back to England's monestaries with very good wage / price records for theoretical reasons.  The 2000 year run is impossible.  Ask about the meaning of wealth and poverty in Rome instead.

Comment: worse, even today "poverty" is hardly defined, and certainly not by buying power or the amount of money one has. E.g. visiting an on paper dirt poor village in central Asia a few years ago I found the people not lacking in anything except modern communications (there was but one TV and one phone in the village). And in the modern US and EU, people are considered poor who have multiple cars, wide screen televisions, etc. etc..

Comment: It's a fine question - comparative standards of living and class structure is a hot topic in history. The answers may kerfluffle some political ideologues on the right side of the spectrum, but that's never a bad thing.

Comment: The richest ancient Roman could not buy a cell phone, so they were poorer than everyone today.

Comment: I've tried to revise the question to emphasize the economic history angle and to remove some of the issues that generated more heat than light. I think this is within the class of valid questions about history.

Comment: Do you include slaves? Or other people who had literally zero purchasing power (as the poor did not have any social welfare or such that time)?

Answer (score 12):

It was more. In 2006 Walter Schiedel wrote an interesting working paper on Roman incomes ("New ways of studying incomes in the Roman economy") which you can find on the web. However, Schiedel's paper just scratches the surface.

When Cicero, a very frugal and honest man, ruled as governor of Cilicia, a relatively poor province, he made 2.1 million sesterces, or about 5500 ounces of gold. Today worth about $7 million USD. At this time an ordinary worker might make 10 asses a day, quite a good wage, which would come out to about $3,600 USD in modern gold terms by the same measure. This would be working "middle class" for a Roman. A poor person might have only enough to scrape by, maybe $1,000 USD a year.

Roman patricians would have dozens, if not hundreds, of servants. How many rich people do you know now who have more than 12 servants?

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference and the example. I also see your point about upper middle class having tons of servants, but one could argue that buying a servant/slave (one-off cost) was less back then, than say, hiring a gardener or babysitter is today (while acknowledging the limitations of such a comparison)

Comment: The paper already addresses this: "broadly speaking, it appears that slaves in classical Athens were 
rather cheap (relative to wage levels), whereas in Roman Egypt (and probably in other 
parts of the empire as well) they were relatively more expensive"

Comment: How many companies do you know now who have more than 12 employees?

Comment: Rich people may not hire many servants now, but someone who makes 1000 times the median wage (eg, $40 million/year) is taking advantage of the labor of 1000 people, even if he does it indirectly through buying physical goods or if he purchases services at a resort.

Comment: I'm not sure what supports your conclusion "it was more." The richest people today make more than 2000x the median wage. E.g., Yanukovich's family amassed perhaps at least $10 billion in a few years in a country where $3600 is still the middle class wage. Lots of Americans make more than $80 million (2000 x 40,000) today, or else we'd hardly have any billionaires.

Comment: They may have made less money than the average American today, but have you considered their cost of living?  The cost of living for the average middle class individual has skyrocketted in the last 30 years.

Comment: While not slaves, babysitters, gardeners, maids, stylists, fashion designers, architects, etc all could be construed to be working in a Rich person's interest nowadays.

Comment: @user1477388: Eh, it's subjective though. Its the cost to maintain "a certain standard of living." You could cut out things like cable, internet, cell phone, car (take a bus, walk, or ride bicycle), not go out to dinner, live in a cheaper area, etc and your cost of living is lower. Our standards have gone up and thus cost of living has gone up.

Comment: I was referring to the standard costs of housing, healthcare, energy, transportation and food which would probably be similar (cars today may be translated to horses in ancient Rome) in which middle class members, today, can barely survive while I don't know how they survived in Ancient Roman times.

Comment: @user1477388: By living off the bare minimums. Housing was much cheaper because it wasn't built to today's standards (or size). Energy use was many orders of magnitude lower. Transportation, for the poor, was exclusively by foot (in fact the defining point of being upper class, _eques_, was access to horses). Etc. Today's lower classes (to say nothing of middle class) are better equipped than the Roman upper class.

Comment: Gold by weight isn't an acceptable purchasing power parity measure and the very meanings of purchase have changed so significantly that it is worthless to attempt a PPP measure across two thousand years.

Comment: @SamuelRussell says you. According to studies I have done, it is a very reliable method of comparing prices over time.

Comment: I think the main point of the OP's question is to compare the gap between the rich and poor in our time and in Ancient Rome.  The gap may or may not have been the same, but it is still definitely a problem today - 1% of the population having over 50% of all wealth.  That's not an economy, that's a pyramid scheme.

Comment: Cicero was by no means frugal. His wife, whose money he wanted to spend like water, kept the reins tight!

Comment: The money Honest old Cicero got from Cicilia was in the form of kickbacks, bribes, and gifts for influence peddling.  This was the case for all Roman governors.

Comment: what is the source for the data about Cicero's wealth?

Comment: Let us be a little rational: it makes no sense in statistical sense to compare extremely rich end of the wealth spectrum (governors, emperors, billioners and such) to an "average wage of middle working class". If there is such thing as middle class or working in antiquity.

Comment: @Greg Why not? I think it is perfectly rational. In fact, if we compare the rich of today, to the rich of 1924, we can see that the disparity in income was much larger just 90 years ago than it is now. In Roman times, it was much more extreme.

Comment: Tyler, Excellent answer: you define your methodology (using gold), you give precise numbers, and you answer the question. I believe many of the comments above criticizing it are misguided (or politically motivated).

Answer (score 3):

In finding reliable resources to answer this question I stumbled upon Author Mayer, Emanuel. The ancient middle classes : urban life and aesthetics in the Roman Empire, 100 BCE-250 CE. It contains a clear understanding of Roman class structure from both a social and economic perspective and it comes with data, which, if used to compare with data about current societies (Piketty's book on Capital in XXI century, for instance) could give you a solid understanding of the difference between the ancient and current social strata.

Comment: Mind to summarize or at least cherry-pick some number for people who do not stumble upon this essay/book/research paper of whatever it is?